# Multiplication law in a central simple algebra of dimension 9 over a global field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, brauer-groups, central-simple-algebras

Let $k$ be a global field, for example $k=\Bbb Q$.
Let  $D$ denote the central simple algebra of dimension 9 over $k$ with given local invariants $i_v$.
Here $v$ runs over the set $\Omega_f(k)$ of finite places of $k$,
$\, $  $i_v\in \frac13\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z$, $\, $
$i_v=0$ for almost all $v$, $\, $ and $\sum_v i_v=0$.

> **Question.** How can one *explicitly* describe the multiplication law in $D$ in terms of the local invariants $i_v$?

**Motivation.** From the multiplication law in $D$, I can obtain the commutation law in the 8-dimensional  Lie algebra ${\frak g}={\frak sl}(1,D)$.
From $\frak g$, I can obtain an explicit trilinear alternating form on the 8-dimensional space $\frak g$:
$$(x,y,z)\mapsto ([x,y],z)\quad\text{for }\,x,y,z\in{\frak g},$$
where $(\,,\,)$ denotes the Killing form.
This is a $k$-form of a generic alternating trilinear form on $\bar k^8$.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but I can tell you the form it will probably have. Take a cyclic cubic field $L$ over $k$ which is not split (either ramified or inert) at every place $v$ where $i_v \neq 0$. The algebra will be generated by $L$ and $\sigma$ where conjugation by $\sigma$ acts on $L$ as a generator of the Galois group, and $\sigma^3 \in L$ is a particular element. The main game is to choose this element to get the right invariants.

Comment: This will amount to a congruence condition at the finitely many primes with nontrivial invariants and the finitely many ramified primes of $L$, plus the condition that at every non-split unramified prime $v$ with $i_v=0$, the $v$-adic valuation of the element is a multiple of $3$. I don't think one necessarily has a formula for such an element in terms of the invariants so I don't know how explicit one can make it, but one can certainly make it more explicit than this.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Note that, since all the local invariants are killed by 3, your $D$ has exponent (and then index ) dividing $3$. Hence $D\simeq M_3(D')$, where $D'$ is a central simple algebra of degree $3$. I assume that not all your local invariants are $0$, so $D'$ is actually division. It might simplify your computation...